# Android : override BackButton when menu is visible

Tags: android, back-button

Let's say I have an activity A that overrides the back button to show some dialog and that this activity has a menu.
So, when the back button is pressed the dialog shows up, but if the user press the menu button and then the back button, the dialog isn't shown. How can I make the behavior for the back button be the same whether the menu is visible or not?

Comment: Do you want the menu to close in addition to the dialog being shown? Or just the dialog to be shown?

Comment: @FoamyGuy Just the dialog to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the BackButton.

```
onBackPressed()
{

    closeOptionsMenu(); // to close the Options Menu if it is visible

      //your code here
}
```

Comment: I've done that to the activity, but this method isn't called if the menu is visible.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't the BackButton always start by removing the menu if it's visible?

Comment: @Slickelito yes, but I'm playing around with android, trying out some stuff :-)

Comment: @AndersMetnik well, at least for the Activity where the menu is opened I did override onBackPressed. The thing is that looks like the overridden method is not called if the menu is visible.

Comment: try closeOptionsMenu(); to close the menu

Comment: @swayam my problem is not closing the menu. What I want is to do something when the menu is visible and the BackButton is pressed. The problem is that it's not enough just to override onBackPressed() by the activity.

Comment: Could you please tell me what happens now when you press the BackButton when the menu is visible ? Does it do anything ? Does it close the menu ?

Comment: it closes the menu... onBackPressed isn't even called.

Comment: yes, that would be it. I mean the dialog is just an idea, it could be anything.

Comment: I might be wrong but to me it seems that the property of the BackButton when the menu is visible is to close it and that behaviour cant be overridden (maybe because you would need to close the options menu first before proceeding any further and hence Android does not let you override it). I mean, otherwise the above method would have surely worked. Here is an idea. Just an idea. What ever options you are displaying in the menu, why don't you show them  via a dialog instead of the OptionsMenu. That way you could dismiss the dialog easily and BackButton could be overridden. Just a thought.

Comment: well, I believe you are right. Android probabily doesn't allow what I was looking for... I'll consider other alternatives. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    }
    return true;
}
```

hope this help